# GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation:true) to a MasterDetailPage is not working on UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, prism, master-detail

I'm creating a Xamarin Forms app that uses Prism. The solution has the three projects that Xamarin supports: Android, iOS and UWP. The app starts on a MainPage(MasterDetailPage) that has two children pages: Promotions and Account.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"
              ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped"                                                
                                              Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
                                              EventArgsParameterPath="Item"/>
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type viewModels:MasterItem}">
                <viewModels:MasterItem Title="Promoções" Path="PromotionsPage"/>
                <viewModels:MasterItem Title="Conta" Path="AccountPage"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

When user navigates to AccountPage, the app verify if the user is logged. If not, a modal page is shown with SignInPage.

```
    ...
    private async void ItemTapped(MasterItem masterItem)
    {
        if (masterItem.Title.Equals("Conta"))
        {
            if (isLogged)
                await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/AccountPage");
            else
                await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/SignInPage", useModalNavigation:true);
        }
        else
        {
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/" + masterItem.Path);
        }
    }
    ...
```

In SignInPage there's a Cancel button to go back to MainPage. On Android, when the user goes back, the MainPage(MasterDetailPage) menu shows properly. But on UWP it is not working.

Comment: How did you want the MainPage(MasterDetailPage) menu to display?

Comment: The problem is because when the user goes back to MasterDetailPage, the hamburger menu doesn't work. I've created a repository on Github to show the problem. Clone to your machine and try to execute the UWP project. You'll see that when the app pops up the modal page and come back to MasterDetailPage, the hamburger menu doesn't work anymore. https://github.com/Schinwinkwinsky/XamarinForms_Prism_MasterDetail_ListView/tree/modalNavigation

Comment: Hmmm, I did see the 'SignInPage' and the 'Cancel' button.

Comment: Yeah. But did you try to push Cancel and go to SignInPage again?

Comment: If you check the visual tree, you will see a rectangle covering the main page. Please report this issue to [Prism Github Issues](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1860